# Are field collections suitable to model single instances of hosted entities?

Tags: 7, entities

I know that field collection is suitable for dynamic content, in which I can put many instances of the same hosted entity embedded in a host entity.

But, if I have a host entity composed by a single instance of different embedded entities, each one with almost the same fields (like in my example underneath) but semantically different, from a architectural and performance point of view, is a good choice to model each hosted entity as a different field collection for reusing the same fields, or is more convenient to create as much similar fields as required to model all the embedded entities?

#### My example:

I've an entity that models a registration, each instance has three profiles, one for the customer, one for the bill and one for other contacts. The three profiles can be all different or all the same, but they must be semantically separated.
Each profile has almost the same fields (addressfield, email, phone, mobile phone and so on).
In this case is better to create three different versions of each field, or to create three field collections type, each one with the same fields?